# wijmo date picker max date

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-2, wijmo

How to set max date today in wijmo calendar?

Here is my code:

```
$(function () {
    $("#calendar1").wijcalendar({
        popupMode: true,
        selectedDatesChanged: function () {
            var selDate = $(this).wijcalendar("getSelectedDate");
            var _selDate = dateFormat(selDate, "mm/dd/yyyy");
            if (!!selDate) $("#begindate").val(_selDate);
        }
    });

    $("#begindate").click(function () {
        $("#calendar1").wijcalendar("popup", {
            of: $("#begindate"),
            offset: '0 2'
        });
    })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a maxDate property:

```
$(".selector").wijcalendar({
 maxDate: new Date(2010,8,15)
```

});

Link: http://wijmo.com/wiki/index.php/Calendar

Answer (score 0):

got the answer:

```
$(function () {
    $("#calendar1").wijcalendar({
        popupMode: true,
        maxDate: new Date(),
        selectedDatesChanged: function () {
            var selDate = $(this).wijcalendar("getSelectedDate");
            var _selDate = dateFormat(selDate, "mm/dd/yyyy");
            if (!!selDate) $("#begindate").val(_selDate);
        }
    });

    $("#begindate").click(function () {
        $("#calendar1").wijcalendar("popup", {
            of: $("#begindate"),
            maxDate: new Date(),
            offset: '0 2'
        });
    })
});
```